# WordPress Navigation Bar Menu in Mobile Phones with CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need help with Navigation Bar Menus in Smartphones with CSS
On a computer the website is fine, but on a smartphone it's a white box

The only way I can customize it, is with Additional CSS

I know that most of the code I use is worthless

All I want is to remove the white box in Mobile View

Please see the screenshots
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV5Rz.jpg)
The website is at https://www.elans.gr

[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfPYp.jpg)

The code I use:

```
   .header-filter-gradient {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
}
.header-filter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.header-filter-gradient {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00000 0%, #00000 100%);
}

.navbar {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}

.navbar.active {
    background-color: #424bf4;
    color: white;

}

.navbar.hover:not(.active) 
{
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add following css in your style.css

```
 @media (max-width: 768px) { 
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {

 background: #211818; //color that you need to change
 color: red !important; // your text  color
              }}
```

Comment: @MariosT. i have updated my answer to include the text color